# Adding gears to my grandson's 12" bike

Tags: bike-fit, children

My grandson has the kind of bike you pedal backwards to brake, and he goes riding with me on my days off.  Yesterday, he asked me if we can convert his bike because we have looked everywhere and no one seems to have a gear-shifting bike for someone who is 8.  The Problem is that he is having trouble keeping up with me and wearing out a lot earlier because of the hills.  Are there bikes with 18" or less wheels that shift or is he still too small for that kind of riding?  I am pretty sure that I can figure out how to mount the gears and get a small derailleur just to learn how to shift and I am pretty sure I can change his brake system to the handlebar levers, but not sure it would be so wise, if I could just get his parents, who are willing and more financially able, to replace the bike with one that is built to be a dirt bike and not a trick bike frame with attachments to help him go faster.

I am pretty sure it is possible and I may even be able to make it just like mine but not sure how cost effective it is if he can just buy one.

I am still learning what different bikes are called.  But he is about 3ft tall and his bike is getting too small for him.  His current bike has 12" wheels.

Comment: I got my first bike IIRC at my 7th birthday and it was 24" wheel size with 3 gears internal hub (also coaster brake). My guess would be that the 18" bike may be too small for him anyways.

Comment: He is still only 3 ft 4-6 inches tall, he is glued to his 12" bike now but I had to pull the seat all the way up and it was just right for him.  I do not know, but he also took the training wheels off himself when he was 6 so he could take that bike to the skate park, so he might be able to handle a 20 or more

Comment: 1 - 1.05 m (if I calculated correctly) is shorter than 8 year-olds are usually around here, so 24" would still be too big. 20" bikes around here are available with gears, either internal hub (possibly with coaster brake) or derailleur.  Random webpage tells me that 20" are for 53+ cm, 24" from 63 cm inseam on, that is inseam ≈ max. wheel diameter.

Comment: A look through classified ads around here suggests that you may be able to find an 18" bike with 3 gear internal hub. If 20" is still too big, 18" and in a few years 24" may be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I did a google search and found some I can order online from BMX that has 7-speed drivetrain,  I like your idea about 18" then 24"  it will give him time to grow.  And he takes pretty good care of his stuff, for an 8 year old so spending higher for something may work out good

Comment: Are you able to lower your own output to match his?

Comment: I can only lower so far before the strain is too much for my knees.  Basically, in first gear for me it is a perfect match pedal for pedal, so I do not change gears, however, obviously because I much heavier than her is, I lose him if we are going downhill and the main trail we ride on, I can coast for most of when heading home but he has pedal through so I know he is not going to be able to just ride with me.  The main thing I am looking for, is reducing the strain on the hills for him so he can keep going.  Like I said, I have slowed to just above his speed.  I may have to adjust where we go

Comment: Oh, and thanks for grammar corrections, I totally missed the difference is spelling break and brake, lol

Comment: Is his saddle high enough? I see lots of children with the saddle way too low which in itself is bad for the knees and efficiency but also forces them to get out of the saddle all the time which is tiring.

Comment: I have the seat as high as it will go it is up to his waist

Comment: Why not let him set the pace?

Comment: I agree with you @Reid, it is his issue not mine I am trying to correct.  Once a week he gets on his 12" bike and rides with me as much of the distance I ride everyday that he can handle.  We have ridden 12.6 of the 14.4 miles I do everyday and that is with us stopping and him climbing trees and playing at every park we come to, his keeping up with me is not my issue.  He is fine, he is upset that his bike is not as fast as mine.  He sees me going slower for him, and it upsets him.  That is all, so I am trying to help him get as close to as fast as me as he can. Does that explain it better?

Comment: Even if you can't go to a 20" yet at least go to 16".  Then you start to be in the wheel (but not frame) size realm of some of the more compact adult folding bikes and there may be internal or at a stretch even external gearing mechanisms that work.  But how fast are you hoping to go together?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your grandson is that young, he's likely to have trouble keeping up with you no matter what bike he's riding. It may be that it's your expectations, not his bike, that should be modified.

It seems *really unlikely* that you could retrofit a derailleur onto his current bike. A frame that small won't have room for a wider rear-wheel assembly. Mounting rim brakes would be tough if the frame isn't already set up for it. Even if you did succeed, he'd still be driving it with eight-year-old legs and an eight-year-old's heart and lungs.

Might you consider a [tagalong bike](http://www.cyclesprog.co.uk/carrying-kids-on-bikes/tagalongs/best-tagalong-bikes/), mounted to your bike? Your grandson might balk at this if he's used to his own separate bike, but it *would* ensure that he keeps up with you.

Comment: I do not know, @jeffB.  He comes really close to keeping up now, just wears out from pedaling so much.  You may be right though, that was part of why I am ok with him riding now, if he stays with it, by the time he is old enough to really ride with me, he will still want to.  converting his bike may be too much.  I actually think a tag-along is great idea and he might be up for it more since I already slow way down to ride with anyway, so me doing most of the work would be fine and reinforce his idea that PopPop is superman, lol

Comment: "Really unlikely" is probably understatement - I think 20' is the smallest you can do it safely (i.e. look at [Navara Duster 20](https://www.rei.com/product/760873/novara-duster-20-6-speed-bike) - there is really not much space left between derailleur and ground). These bikes get very little use - so should be easy to find used one in like-new condition for price of new derailleur alone.

Comment: 8 is too old for a tagalong bike. He should get a real one.

Comment: @Nobody With respect, the child in question is off the height-distribution charts, and "one-size-fits-all" advice is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: +1 for "your expectations".

Comment: An alternative to a tagalong is a tandem with a kid-back stoker system.

Answer (score 12):

Is he extremely short? An 8-year-old is almost 9 years old, and: "26 inch mountain bikes are suited for kids that are 9-13 years old." Don't fix up the 12 incher. Head into a local bike shop and get a proper sizing.

Comment: Cheeky, but go in to the shop to get the right size, then get one 2nd hand for 1/10th the price, if you think he might put on a growth spurt.   Any decent bike shop will be used to sizing for kids that will grow so will suggest the largest bike he can handle now so that he has growing room.

Comment: He is super short for his age, between 3 and 3 and half feet tall.  He has always been really small.

Comment: @LorenStevenson I hadn't realized just _how_ unusually short your grandson is for his age. You can throw all the typical-bike-size-for-age advice out the window. Much will depend on his leg length, and whether he has other health issues.

Comment: Yeah @jeffB he is super tiny

Comment: @jeffB, for context, my son just turned two years old, and he's nearly as tall as OPs grandson. Kids have a pretty wide range of dimensions.

Comment: @whatsisname That's also unusual.  3'6" is average for 4-5 years old.  At two your son is about 10" over the average for his age.  OP's grandson is about 10" under the average for his age.

Answer (score 7):

If you are absolutely set on converting the bike, use an internal gear hub (IGH). There are IGHs with three gears (the usual kid's first IGH), and there are IGHs with seven gears (suitable for many adults), and both of them are cheap when bought second-hand. The last IGH I bought was a seven gear with coaster brake which I got second hand for 25 Euros from my local bike shop.

The main cost factor (either time or money for labor) will be rebuilding the wheel with the new hub.

Comment: I am reconsidering rebuilding given everyone's excellent advise
But like the idea of getting a bike with an IGH

Comment: This is the best answer to the question as asked, and probably a good idea if OP feels up to doing it. Adding real brakes will also be needed and may be a bit of work.

Comment: @R.. Well, the coaster brake that comes with most IGHs is a real brake. Since it's actuated by the chain itself and not by a cable that can get stuck or break, coaster brakes are actually quite robust and fail-safe as long as they are not overheated. That is the only real problem with coaster brakes: They lack sufficient area for heat dissipation, and are thus not suitable to handle long descents. Of course, you always need two working brakes on a bike. Of these two, the coaster brake provides one, so there's only one brake left to change for a good one.

Comment: @cmaster: Ah, I wasn't aware IGH's had coaster brakes (and am sorta disgusted that they do, but depending on what OP's grandchild likes it may be a good or a bad thing).

Comment: @R.. There are IGHs with and without coaster brakes. The most expensive ones like the Rohloff don't have coaster brakes because you cannot combine a coaster brake with oil immersion lubrication. But the cheap vanilla IGHs that you see either on children's bikes or on city bikes usually have a coaster brake. I don't know what you find disgusting about coaster brakes, though. I've been riding bikes with such IGHs for thirty years now, and I've always seen them as a near-perfect, reliable, no-fail backup to stop my bike in case of an emergency.

Comment: @cmaster: I find the inability to reverse the pedals while coasting uncomfortable and even moderately unsafe, and the inability to adjust their position when starting from a stop annoying. But if it works for you, great. :-)

Comment: @R.. Yes, with a coaster brake you need to stop pedaling in a position that lends itself to starting again. However, that's quite natural: You already need the pedals in a back-front position for the brake to be fully usable. Of course, I'm used to it, and you are used to a free-wheel, and each of us would have trouble riding the bike of the other, I guess. The reason I love IGHs is the ability to switch at full stop: When braking, I can concentrate on braking, and while standing, I can shift down to leave at full power. The coaster brake, I've always just used it because it was there anyways.

Comment: @cmaster: Yeah. I want my feet/pedals in a 1-7 (vs 3-9) position to start though, which probably goes along with my preference for fixed high gear ratio. This is also one reason I want free-wheeling - ability to back up to a position with more room for acceleration before reaching the point of minimal torque, if I've had to slow down going uphill.

Comment: @R.. I always use a 2-8 position for accelerating, 1-7 seems a bit extreme :-)

Answer (score 3):

Like cmaster mentioned, fitting internal gear hub (even 7-speed) wouldn't be too difficult. It would consist of:

1. Rebuild the wheel around the internal geared hub. This is possible to do at home with basic equipment, takes a few hours to learn but in my experience is quite easy and there are many tutorials online. For a light-use bike, spoke tensiometers and such advanced tools are not mandatory.
2. Route the gear shifting cable from back wheel to handlebar. I guess you could zip-tie it, if you don't find any better method of mounting it.
3. Install gear shifting lever on handlebar.

But if you are aiming for the granddad-of-the-year award, install a front wheel e-bike assist motor also. That will make uphills a breeze. The common cheap kits would probably work, though you should pick one with lowest powered motor and smallest battery to avoid adding too much weight.

Comment: I would love to do that, the motor idea would work If I can afford it

Comment: If you go the electric motor route, you'll have to make sure that what you do is actually legally allowed.

Comment: Rebuilding a wheel is not trivial. You don't have to make the wheel strong for a kids bike, but you'll probably need different length spokes and the spoke length calculation is a pain. Motor kits are designed for full-sized bikes, there won't be enough room on a 12" wheel bike.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus There are online calculators that make the spoke length calculation quite easy, it just requires care in taking measurements. Admittedly the short spokes (~150mm) for 12" wheels are less common, but available at least online. As for the ebike conversion, yeah, it will need some searching to find a suitable motor. However smallest geared motors (such as GBK-100F) in kits are ~120mm flange diameter, which still leaves plenty of space to spoke a 12 inch (300 mm) wheel. The fork width could be more of a problem, though there are special narrow motors also.

Comment: @I'm thinking of battery space as well as the hub motor

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Well, that is even less of a problem. Most kits are sold without battery, so you can select it separately. The common "bottle battery" and "little frog" style cases are quite small, and could fit even a 12" bike's rear rack (assuming it has one, though there are plenty of mounting options).

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is buying a new child's bike off Craigslist, one with gears.  Adding gears to an existing bike will likely cost more than a decent used bike and will not likely end up problem free.

I have an 8 year old and we just got her a new bike with gears, we live in an area that is quite hilly.  She has a 24" hybrid bike (road tires with upright seating) with 14 speeds and grip shifters.  We've gone as many as 12 miles with hills and she has no problems keeping up.  24" may seem big, but the seat on her bike is almost the same height as the tire.

Comment: 'Adding gears to an existing bike will likely cost a more than a decent used bike' absolutely, *especially* a 12" wheel bike.

Comment: Yeah that is what I spent this weekend explaining to my daughter and son-in-law.  We are now looking at splitting the cost

Comment: To answer your question, yes there are some small bikes 18" or less with gears.  I see a few 18" or less bikes with gears for $60 or less on my local Craigs List.  Your luck may vary based on your location.